# Understanding 可能なところ

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 十香は顔を真っ赤にしながら叫びを上げると、身体を覆い隠すようにその場にしゃがみ込んだ。
>
> 「えっ、ええっ！？いや、それは十香が自分でーー」
>
> 「馬鹿を言うな！自分で服を脱いだなら忘れるはずがないだろう！は……っ、まさか<ハニエル>で私の服を……！？」
>
> 「ち、違う！濡れ衣だ！」
>
> <ハニエル>であれば可能**なところ**が苦しかったが、士道としてはそう言う他なかった。必死に頭を振り、無実を訴える。

What does the ところ mean here? Is it like ~な感じ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That ところ simply means a point or part of something.

In this context, it refers to a particular aspect of what Shido has to deny. <ハニエル>であれば可能なところが苦しかった is something like “the part about *Haniel* being indeed capable of it was hard to explain away.”